# mqsql product/option compatibility

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

I need to manage some relations for a product configuration tool.
For easy setup i want to link the configuration product (future called: option) to the product instead of reversed. This way it requires way less insertion.

The relation is based on the product details. 
For example i have a product of the follow config

```
- Height: 1  
- Width:  1
- Color:  Black
```

Then i have two entities of option with the following config: the first one is correct but the second aint't.
The first:

```
 - Height: [1, 2]  
 - Width:  [1, 2, 3]  
 - Color:  NULL
```

The second:

```
 - Height: [2]
 - Width:  [1, 2, 3]
 - Color:  NULL
```

How do i get the options (with only the id of the product) that are compatible with my product.

Keep in mind: the above shown data is in human readable format. the option and product have a many-to-many relation with the specification. and specification has then a type assigned.

The logic in base lines:

- if a option has no specs assigned of a certain type, that type is irrelevant.
- The relevant types of the option all have to contain the specs of the product.

Tables relations:

```
 - Edition       > - < Specification  
 - Option        > - < Specification  
 - Specification > - 1 Specgroup
```

[Full view of database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iUsyF.png)

Comment: Can you share with us what your database schema looks like so far?

Comment: Done, the link is at the button (full view of database).